# Heroku: Missing Numpy Package

Tags: python, numpy, heroku

I am unable to open my Heroku app and am receiving errors related to loading numpy even though 1) my code does not explicity include numpy and 2) I have pip installed it within the app (see requirements). Any idea why this will not work?

Error:

```
2020-05-24T15:41:56.985029+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: The figure factory module requires the numpy package
2020-05-24T15:41:56.985615+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-24 15:41:56 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
2020-05-24T15:41:57.156552+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-24 15:41:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-24T15:41:57.156769+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-24 15:41:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-05-24T15:41:57.256186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-05-24T15:41:57.316857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-24T16:11:37.566673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=protected-peak-02571.herokuapp.com request_id=e9e96cec-158a-45b4-a1b1-b5250721be05 fwd="205.178.3.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-24T16:11:37.969514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=protected-peak-02571.herokuapp.com request_id=8010a2fc-190f-4fda-b07a-ca35a09ee748 fwd="205.178.3.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-24T16:12:30.469542+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=protected-peak-02571.herokuapp.com request_id=0ca9d3ab-9b25-4522-9eb4-49ee65e3aee8 fwd="205.178.3.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
Brotli==1.0.7
click==7.1.2
dash==1.12.0
dash-core-components==1.10.0
dash-html-components==1.0.3
dash-renderer==1.4.1
dash-table==4.7.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Compress==1.5.0
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.18.4
pandas==1.0.3
plotly==4.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.15.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Comment: Could you try adding `numpy` on top of your `requirements.txt?`

Comment: You mean reordering the line item in the .txt file? It looks to be in ABC order. I also just tried this with no change in result

Comment: The error is resulting because `plotly` is not able to "retrieve" `numpy`.  See this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/figure_factory/__init__.py#L6